# C Graphics Library Error

Tags: c, bgi

I have the following code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<graphics.h>
void main()
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    int dx,dy,p,end;
    float x1,x2,y1,y2,x,y;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
    printf("\nEnter the value of x1: ");
    scanf("%f",&x1);
    printf("\nEnter the value of y1: ");
    scanf("%f",&y1);
    printf("\nEnter the value of x2: ");
    scanf("%f",&x2);
    printf("\nEnter the value of y2: ");
    scanf("%f",&y2);
    dx=abs(x1-x2);
    dy=abs(y2-y1);
    p=2*dy-dx;

    if(x1>x2)
    {
        x=x2;
        y=y2;
        end=x1;
    }
    else
    {
        x=x1;
        y=y1;
        end=x2;
    }
    putpixel(x,y,10);
    while(x<end)
    {
        x=x+1;
        if(p<0)
        {
            p=p+2*dy;
        }
        else
        {
            y=y+1;
            p=p+2*(dy-dx);
        }
        putpixel(x,y,10);
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

The code is mainly for creating a line. But when I run this program I get error message in my console(I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 version) as :

`test.c:2: fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
test.c:2: fatal error: graphics.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Is that mean I have to add some lib to C path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`conio.h` and `graphics.h` are ancient, non-standard interfaces that came from Borland environments I suppose.

Comment: In Ubuntu environment I didn't install C, but i can run other C programs without any error but in this case i can't :/

Comment: This program is probably written for an MS-DOS environment, and would never compile in a standard Linux distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Those two headers are Windows-only. For `getch()` you can emulate it (see [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/faq-board/27714-faq-there-getch-conio-equivalent-linux-unix.html)) and for `graphics.h` you can install [libgraph](http://zaher14.blogspot.com/2007/01/graphicsh-in-linux.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu users the mistake is when we dont have that library. So we include a corresponding library. Type the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
dx=abs(x1-x2);
```

by this:

```
dx=abs(x2-x1);
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use `OPENGL` and delete the line including `conio.h`,`graphics.h`,`getch()`,`closegraph()`. Those are used by Turbo C DOS compiler and are obsolete.